# Docker compose permission denied when PHP-FPM trying to create directory

Tags: docker, permissions, postgresql, docker-compose, alpine

I have this docker-compose I'm experimenting with. Im using fastCGI from Nginx to run the script.

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

  services:
    psqldb:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/psql/Dockerfile
        args:
          UID: "${UID}"
          GID: "${GID}"
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER:  postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: d;%f=68ZXJENER-R
        PGDATA: /pg-data
      volumes:
        - ./docker/.data/pgsql/:/pg-data
        - ./docker/.log/pgsql/:/var/log/postgresql/
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    phpapp:
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile_dev
        args:
          UID: "${UID}"
          GID: "${GID}"
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        DB_HOST: psqldb
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: d;%f=68ZXJENER-R
        DEBUG_MODE: 1
      volumes:
        - ./docker/php-fpm/config/zzz-phpSettings.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-phpSettings.conf
        - ./docker/.log/phpfpm/:/var/log/
        - ./phpcode/:/var/www
      depends_on:
        - psqldb
```

The PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0.9-fpm-alpine

ARG UID
ARG GID

RUN addgroup --gid GID docker
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid $UID --gid $GID docker
USER docker

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update \
RUN apk add \
    build-base \
    vim \
    tzdata

# set Timezone
ENV TZ=Europe/Prague

# FIX for PDO-PGSQL
RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
    postgresql-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

EXPOSE 9000
```

The problem is that the volume directories for log and data are created under ROOT user and not under the specified user.
How to solve that? I've tried many internet tips for this and this is the last I found, so how can I make it run without `chowning` all the time?